# Divisibility bound on sums of numbers

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $p$ and $q$ are two prime numbers. Let $N(p)$ be the set of natural numbers that are divisible only by primes $\leq p$. Define $N(q)$ similarly.

If $N(p,q)$ is the set of numbers that can be written as a sum of a number in $N(p)$ and a number in $N(q)$, what is the upper bound on the primes that can divide numbers in $N(p,q)$, if any?

Comment: Usually there's very little we can say about the factorization of $a+b$ given the factorizations of $a$ and $b$. In particular, I don't see any reason to expect an upper bound for the prime factors involved in this set of sums; it seems reasonable even to conjecture that there are infinitely many such sums that are themselves prime.

Comment: @Simplicious I was mistaken; it is indeed fairly easy to demonstrate that there is no upper bound. I was trying to prove a result that was too strong. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every prime number $p$ we have $1,2^{2^n}\in N(p)$, and hence $2^{2^n}+1\in N(p,q)$ for any pair of prime numbers $(p,q)$. The number $F_n:=2^{2^n}+1$ is called the $n$-th [Fermat number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number). It is currently unknown whether there are only finitely many Fermat primes or not, despite the fairly generous attention it receives.

It is known, however, that every prime factor $p$ of the Fermat number $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ satisfies
$$p\equiv1\pmod{2^{n+2}}.$$
In particular every prime factor of $F_n$ satisfies $p>2^{n+2}$, and hence there exist arbitrarily large prime numbers dividing numbers of the form $2^{2^n}+1$. This shows that $N(p,q)$ is unbounded for all pairs of primes $(p,q)$.